# Spring Data JPA repository multi-tenant single schema technique

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant, spring-data

I'm just getting started on a spring app that is currently using spring data with a jpa repository.  I'm planning on the app being a multi-tenant app using a single database schema.  What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to attach the tenant id to each query.  Of course I can write each query in the repository to expect a tenant id parameter and grab the tenant id out of a thread local or similar, but I was wondering if there was a better technique that is commonly used in this situation?  Maybe there is a more declarative way to do it that I haven't come across yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spring JPA over some JPA implementation (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc.). So, you need to configure multitenancy at JPA provider level. For hibernate - [see here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)

Also you may check alternative way - [this](http://habrahabr.ru/post/113721/) (warning: RUSSIAN language inside)

Comment: I am using hibernate but hibernate does not support the discriminator approach to multi-tenancy until 5.0, so I will probably need to roll my own solution for the time being.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your answer boils down to: use hibernate filters.  At first glance it doesn't appear that there is a good life cycle method or similar to implement to gain access to the hibernate session and dynamically decide if I should apply the filter. The article you linked extends HibernatePersistence which seems like a good way to go if you want to apply the filter for every query.  I probably won't need to apply the filter on a 100% of my queries, maybe I should look at extending the base repo.